128-bit hashes for signature schemes?
Under what circumstances would it be tolerable to use 128-bit hashes for the purposes of digital signatures?
What are the practical implications of lack of collision resistance in such a setting?
Assuming that third-parties cannot get you to sign arbitrary messages, does it even matter?
Also the entire bitcoin network is only 2^75 sha256 ops per year.
So why would anyone even want more than 128 bits of security for something like a signature scheme? Where the payoff is impersonation.

Actually, SLH-DSA (Sphincs+) can use 128 bit hashes, and still get "128 bit strength".
It does this by including a randomizer in the initial hash; because the randomizer cannot be predicted by the adversary selecting the messages to be signed, collision resistance is not needed - instead, we rely on second preimage resistance.

How does that work when WOTS+ security degrades to something like 110 bits with w=16?

@LamiraYa: no, it doesn't.  You do realize that WOTS+ (or SLH-DSA) includes a distinguisher for each step of the Winternitz chain, preventing multitarget attacks

The WOTS+ paper clearly states the security for n=128 is b=113. Table 1. https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/965.pdf

That was with w=21 but b doesn't appear to be particularly sensitive to minor changes in w. I also used the equation.

@LamiraYa: I believe those are the results that Andreas could prove at the time, not the actual security level. We now have proofs with better security guarantees.

Doesn't this mean that WOTS+ signatures can then be made small? with n=m=128 and w=4096, sig size is 192 bytes. however b=100, is that b incorrect according to newer proofs?

For $n=m=128$ and $w=4096$, I get $208$ bytes - $11$ hashes for the message part of the chain, $2$ for the checksum, with each hash being $16$ bytes - $(11 + 2) \times 16 = 208$

I see. What about a better security proof, do you have a reference?
